# Python increment loop to add filter parameters to dataframe

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, while-loop

I created a dictionary with a set of functions. Then, I created a while loop that attempts to use those functions. But part of the loop doesn't call the functions the way I want it to. Here's the code:

```
while bool(str(w).endswith(' 2')) != True:
    a = re.search('[0-9]{1,2}$', str(w))
    w = w & int(a.group())-1
    result = df[f[w]]
```

The third line, `w = w & int(a.group())-1`, doesn't function the way I want when I test it outside of this loop. I try setting `w = 34`, and then testing what results when I do `34 & int(a.group())-1`. Instead of giving me `34 & 33`, I get `32`. Is there any way to create an increment that adds parameters to the result, instead of creating some integer that doesn't even seem to be derived logically? I would like it to start with 34, and add an integer that is one less for every go around the loop (`34`, `34 & 33`, `34 & 33 & 32`, etc.). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please give more info: what values do `int(a.group())` return?

Comment: Starting with with w = 34, int(a.group())-1 returns 33.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I needed q = f[w] and then q = q & f[w-n], where f[w] defines parameters to filter a dataframe (df) based on a column, and f[w-n] defines a different parameter for filtering based on the next adjacent column. So, the progression should be f[w], f[w] & f[w-n], f[w] & f[w-n] & f[w-n], etc., instead of 34, 34 & 33, 34 & 33 & 32, etc. while n <= w.

So that would look like this:

```
w = 34
n = 1
q = f[w]
while n <= w:
    q = q & f[w-n]
    result = df[q]
    n = n+1
```

And, there would be conditions later on to decide whether or not enough parameters were used. In my usage, I'm not looking for a result before the while loop after q is initially defined because that result would have already been found in a different portion of the program. (In case this helps anyone else.)

[Scott Hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535275/scott-hunter) thanks for the tip on the & operator.

Answer (score 3):

`34 & 33` *is* `32`.  `&` is the bitwise and operator.

Saying you want `"34 & 33"` suggests that you want a *string* as a result, but that seems to conflict w/ the use of `str(w)` throughout your code.  Or maybe you are just unclear about what `&` does, and really want some different operation.